# Office365 delta API for drive items - sharing changes

Tags: api, sharepoint, permissions, office365, delta

I'm using the delta API for drive items to track the changes for files in the drives, but I'm not getting any result from the delta when changing the permission for a file, only results for delete, create, modify (I thought for permission changes I'll see a result with the modify action).
Is this supported? Or permission changes will not give me a new delta result?
Thanks.